# Aspnet core request count logging

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have 2 controller and each controller has 2 endpoints. For example:

```
 GET /categories
 GET /category/{id}
```

Basically I want to know how many one or another endpoint is being used.
So the final result I want to count the calls. For example one endpoint was used X amount of times and another used Y amount of times. And I want to get this string: `$"{id} is the most popular category"`

How to do it? I need a statistic for my web api

Comment: Create a static `ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>` with key is your id, then increment the value threadsafe using [Interlocked.Increment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=net-5.0) might be what you want for a simple project. To be more decent, i suggest you trying out redis.

Comment: You can use [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0)  to check the url.

Comment: I think I will use prometheus and grafana for metrics
it is better in my opinion @GordonKhanhNg.